# Centralized div between two div's using only CSS

Tags: css

I would like to know how do i centrilize one div, with unknown `width` only using `CSS`.

I desire something like:

[image]

Using `<center>` i have:

```
<div style="float: left">
    <p:commandButton  .../>
</div>
<center>
    <p:commandButton ..."/>
    <p:commandButton .../>
</center>
<div style="float: right">
    <p:commandButton .../>
</div>
```

How do that only using `css`?

Note: I don't use `margin: 0 auto` just because the size of centralized div is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

1) Set `text-align:center` on the parent div (ie the parent of the elements which you have mentioned)

2) Replace the `center` element with a `div` and set the rule `display:inline-block` on it.

FIDDLE

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
.middleBtns {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="float: left">
    <button type="button">
      < </button>
  </div>
  <div class="middleBtns">
    <button type="button">btn1</button>
    <button type="button">btn2</button>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right">
    <button type="button">></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get asked a lot here, look here [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Essentially the inner element that you are wanting to center requires a display type of inline:block; and the container wrapping this element which you want to center it in you set a property of text-align:center;